# How not to set always DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE?

Tags: django

I have project with difference settings for prod and local how to set default settings(local for example).

So that after some time I go to the project and I would not have to set the settings again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a condition based on the app environment in the `settings.py` file.

something like `APP_ENV = 'Prod'` or `APP_ENV = 'Local'`

And create the settings with the `if-else` condition

```
if APP_ENV == 'Prod':
    #all prod settings
else:
    #all local settings
```

so just by changing the value of `APP_ENV` in your settings file, you can toggle between the settings that need to be applied